# PHP Zip Archive Extract Not working When Script is Executed by Crontab

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

Within my script I need to connect to ftp and download few zips files and then extract them in a directory. I have already got this implemented and it works as expected when I run the script through browser but when the `crontab` run this script it throws me error that it failed to extract file. I tried to research but I had no luck I don't understand the reason for this.

Below is the error that I am getting:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning
Message ZipArchive::extractTo(/home/name/files/complete//filename.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied
Filename: controllers/import.php
Line Number: 66
```

Script:

```
$txt_file: "/home/name/files/complete/Data.zip";
$server_txt_file = "/TXT/Data.zip";

if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $txt_file, $server_txt_file, FTP_BINARY))
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($txt_file) === TRUE) 
    {
        $zip->extractTo('/home/name/files/complete/');
        $zip->close();
        unlink($txt_file);
    }
}
```

I am trying to fix this for days now but I can not figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you everything you need to know:

`failed to open stream: Permission denied`.

So your php process has no permission to write to the specified folder. So you should change the permissions of specified folder.

Comment: I know that and I have got the permissions right too. It works when I run it through browser but fails when crontab run the exript.

Comment: @user4676307: When you run php code from command line. The script runs with your user permission , not with www-data user permissions.

Comment: thank you for your comment I now understand why I am getting this error. Will you be able to help to on how to change this permission on server I have never done things like this before.

Comment: Sure check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/303593/how-can-i-chmod-777-all-subfolders-of-var-www) out. But make sure you only use the permissions necessary. `0777` could be bad for security matters.